# Alter WordPress theme nav bar positioning

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation

I am attempting to move a WP theme's nav bar next to its designated logo area to no avail (like this: http://screencast.com/t/UsPhTZ3SM) Any ideas? Here is the header.php code: http://pastebin.com/mr7mtpMG

Many thanks,

Alex

Comment: Can you post a link for one to look at the nav?

Comment: Surely: http://mefo1.ecin1prod1lnx1.com/. Thank you

Comment: Are you going to have the search box below the nav? I dont think you can fit that row next to the logo. Know what I mean?

Comment: Yes I do. The position of the search box isn't super important. It could stay above and the nav items could go below or the search can go below the nav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you and trying to simply move the Nav under the header, I would just switch these sections.  But that's me, and I'm a big fan of trial and error...

```
<div id="top-header"> <!-- top navigation bar -->
     .....
</div><!--end header-->

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="header"><!-- header -->
     .....
</div><!-- end header -->
```

Switch to:

```
<div id="header"><!-- header -->
     .....
</div><!-- end header -->

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="top-header"> <!-- top navigation bar -->
     .....
</div><!--end header-->
```

But again, I'm the type of person that doesn't mind breaking things in the interest of learning...

Comment: Right there with you- you'll never know until you try. Thank you Caleb, this is an awesome starting point, it's almost perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I would re-format the html and cleanup the css(way too many unnecessary floats), but if you want a quick fix, try the following:

```
- #top-header, add position: absolute and margin-left: 26em
- #nav-pages li, add display: inline-block
```

- remove the following properties:

```
#top-header, width: 930px;
#top-header-left, float: left, display: inline;
#nav-pages, #nav-pages ul, float: left
#nav-pages li, float: left
```

NOTE: Not tested on everyones favorite, IE

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Going to give it a go. Thank you!